# Getting strange artifacts in URL from Flask's url_for

Tags: python, flask

I can't seem to find **anything** on this particular problem. I'm using the `url_for` in an html page and it's returning some funky stuff right before the query string.  What's causing the below behavior and how can I get the actual URL to match what's expected?

**The call:** `href="{{ url_for('add_movie', tmdb_id=movie['movie_id']) }}"`

**Expected URL:** '/add?tmdb_id=1234'

**Actual URL:** '/add/**%7Btmdb_id%7D**?tmdb_id=1234' (the strange part in bold)

The list of movies is populated from a function that makes an API call.  I verified that the list of `id`'s returned from the API call looks good.

**Python:**

```py
class TmdbMovie:
    def __init__(self, tmdb_id, title, release_date):
        self.movie_id = tmdb_id
        self.title = title
        self.release_date = release_date

@app.route('/add/{tmdb_id}', methods=['POST'])
def add_movie(tmdb_id):
```

**HTML:**

```html
{% for movie in movies %}
  <p>
    <a href="{{ url_for('add_movie', tmdb_id=movie['movie_id']) }}"> {{ movie['title'] }} - {{ movie['release_date'] }}</a>
  </p>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the route registration, you have to use [angular brackets](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/api/#url-route-registrations) for parameters:

```
@app.route('/add/<tmdb_id>', methods=['POST'])
def add_movie(tmdb_id):
```

The `%7B` and `%7D` strings are URL-encoded `{}` brackets.

Comment: I can't believe I missed that - I knew the fix would be something stupid/simple.  I'll definitely look harder at the encoding strings next time.  It never occurred to me that that's what was going on.  Thank you!